# Gate checking a stroller at San Francisco with Singapore Airlines

Tags: luggage, children, sfo, singapore-airlines

I am traveling with my son on Singapore Airlines from San Francisco International Airport (SFO) to Singapore Changi Airport (SIN).

Does anybody know if they allow gate checking the stroller?

Comment: Did you look at http://www.singaporeair.com/?

Comment: Strangely, nothing relevant to gate check comes up when searching inurl:singaporeair.com stroller, or inurl:flysfo.com stroller ... I suggest calling the Singapore Airlines office at SFO to check what they can offer you.

Comment: I found this little snippet _"If your cabin baggage exceeds these limits, it will be collected and stored in the aircraft cargo compartment."_ which suggests to me that they can do this, however from what I remember in the US due to security precautions, gate checking may not be allowed at all. I think its best to check with the airline directly; their contact number is +1 (800) 742-3333

Comment: Update: There were no problems gate checking the stroller. The lady at the check in tagged the stroller and gave us the option of checking it through to the final destination or take it for use at the transit airport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**.  Most airlines, certainly all majors, such as Singapore, gate check strollers.  They will also be returned at the gate on arrival.

To facilitate the process, see the Gate Agent beforehand so they can tag it.  This will save time at boarding/pre-boarding.

Taking a child stroller/buggy is not at all uncommon but must also meet some practical requirements.  It likely must be **collapsible or foldable** and under a certain weight.  You really want it to fit through the belt scanner at the terminal entrance as well.

Unfortunately, SQ does not publish the specific requirements on their web site, few airlines do.  If you are worried your stroller is too large, you can either call the airline to request the specific requirements or show the agent when you check your other bags.  If it's too large, they will counter check it.

Since you have the stroller, also be sure you meet any child seat requirements: [Child car seats and harnesses](http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/travel-info/special-assistance/travelling-with-children/)

Note, while SQ does not publish the specific requirements, there are a number of similar question out there indicating SQ accepts gate checked strolers just like every other significant carrier.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  Is there anything incorrect?  Otherwise, totally unwarranted.